# Find X position of where user is dragging their finger in ScrollView

Tags: ios, scrollview

I have a scrollview and I'm watching user input. I would like to know where their finger currently is on the X plane. Is this possible through the ScrollView and/or its delegate or do I have to override `touchesBegan`, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you set up your scroll view delegate. If you did, then you only need to implement the `scrollViewDidScroll:` method from the [`UIScrollViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html) protocol...

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGPoint touchPoint = [scrollView.panGestureRecognizer locationInView:scrollView];
    NSLog(@"Touch point: (%f, %f)", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y);
}
```

This will update while the user is scrolling.

**Additional info:** Note that if you have something like a `UIPageControl`, that your scroll view is navigating between, you may have to calculate the x position based on the number of pages (ie if each page is 100 pixels wide, page 0 will start at point 0, page one at point 100, etc..).

Answer (score 1):

```
CGPoint touchPoint = [scrollView.panGestureRecognizer locationInView:scrollView];
CGFloat x = touchPoint.x;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CGPoint point = [_scrollView locationOfTouch:touchIndex inView:_scrollView];
```

touchindex: 0 for first touch and 1, 2,3 so on

if inview:nil then point will be in the window base coordinate sysytem

```
CGFloat x = point.x;
CGFloat y  = point.y
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the panGesture of the scrollView because it's more accurate if you want to know the position of the x plane when you have only vertical scroll.

```
[self.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanForScrollView:)];
```

and then:

```
- (void)handlePanForScrollView:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    CGPoint positionInView = [gesture locationInView:self.scrollView];

}
```